# Effect of Logical Operations on Carry Flag (8085)

Tags: 8085

why carry flag gets affected by logical operations like AND, OR and XOR, with respect to Intel 8085 microprocessor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The carry flag is set to zero for these logical operations. These operations do not carry, nor do they borrow.

Paging through the *8080/8085 Assembly Language Programming Manual* from Intel (© 1978), I can not find any explanation other than that.

Would you know it. Someone actually scanned this book and put it online. See [here](http://www.tramm.li/i8080/Intel%208080-8085%20Assembly%20Language%20Programming%201977%20Intel.pdf). I actually have this book, but the the pdf will make it easier to add the image shown below. This was taken from page 1-10. (Click on image for better view.)

[image]